# Blue Input Screen (Shell Script)

Tags: shell

In Ubuntu Server 10.04

Sometimes when i'm installing some packages through apt-get, it prompts me with a blue dialog and asks for input/selection.. E.G: when installing mysql-server, it prompts me for a root password..
How can i accomplish this in my own shell script, so that same blue dialog will show up when i need to ask yes/no and password questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dialog`. Read more about it [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2460) and [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2807?page=0,0).

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`dialog`](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2807).

Answer (score 1):

Try the `ncurses` library.

http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/

There are some examples of using ncurses stuff (including `dialog`, which is what's probably being used in your examples) from bash here:

http://subsignal.org/doc/AliensBashTutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

In a fairly modern bash:

```
$ read -p 'Password? ' -s; echo "[$REPLY]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zenity`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity) or [`yad`](http://code.google.com/p/yad/wiki/Examples) within your shell script. `yad` (Yet Another Dialog) has been a fork of `zenity` to remove obsoleted dependencies (libglade and gnome-canvas) at a time when `zenity` project was frozen. But now both projects continue to evolve (in different directions)...

You can still use ancestors: [`gdialog`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_gdialog.htm), [`cdialog`](http://freecode.com/projects/cdialog), [`xdialog`](http://xdialog.free.fr/) and [`dialog`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialog_%28software%29).

`zenity` can be used in Python ([PyZenity](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyZenity)), in Ruby ([Zerenity](http://code.google.com/p/zerenity/), [Zenity.rb](http://rubygems.org/gems/Zenity.rb)) and in many shells: `bash`, `tcsh`, `dash`, `zsh`... and even in MS-Windows shell!

Zenity basic example:

```
#!/bin/sh
if zenity --question --text="Please press a button."
then
   zenity --info     --text="You pressed Yes\!"
else
   zenity --error    --text="You pressed No\!"
fi
```